# Strange result using instance methods in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, methods, instance

Wondering how the example below is actually working, and how one would be able to do something like dynamically. Using `call_user_func` or `call_user_func_array` doesn't allow this to happen.

```
<?php
class Person
{
    public $name = "George";

    public function say_hi()
    {
            return ExtraMethods::hi();
    }
}

class ExtraMethods
{
    public function hi()
    {
            return "Hi, ".$this->name;
    }
}

$george = new Person();
echo $george->say_hi();
?>
```

this should result with:

```
Hi, George
```

Wondering why the instance method `hi` can be called not only statically (not surprised that this can happen in PHP), but why I am able to use `$this`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php):

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).

So, according to the second portion, by design. Keep in mind it uses the actual object instance in existance though (in other words, if you add `public $name = "SomethingElse";` to `ExtraMethods`, the result would still be `Hi, George`).

Calling the method statically is not proper coding, but PHP forgives you, and issues only a Strict Error:

```
"Strict Standards: Non-static method ExtraMethods::hi() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in ..."
```

Of course, in this instance, just passing the object as an argument would be far clearer and preferable.

Comment: Ah, makes perfect sense. I'd imagine that this is done for some sort of legacy support?

Comment: Well, PHP4 legacy maybe, the 'static' keyword / static methods weren't available then.